# forLoop & joinField & different names

Tags: arcpy, loop, error-000732

I have a folder with an output (shapefiles) from an iteration. On this output, I want to perform a join between two attributetables.

So far so good. Here comes the tricky part.
There are different shapefiles (lets say 20), all with different names. Each attributetable has exactly the same amount of fields (maybe the numbers of rows differs).
What I want the script to do is: pick two specific attributetables which belong together (based on the name), join them and then go on to the next two attributetables until there are no more tables to join.
All shapefiles have different names, but where the %Name% stands in the script, the name is the same.

For example:

```
abc_clip_diss JOIN abc_full_diss
def_clip_diss JOIN def_full_diss 
ghi_clip_diss JOIN ghi_full_diss
```

What I got so far and is not much because I am very new to python is that:

```
import arcpy

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace =  

#set variables
inFeatures = "%Name%_clip_diss"
joinField = "WLType"
joinTable = "%Name%_clip_full"
fieldList = ["area_ha"]




#JoinField "JoinField_management (in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, {fields})"
JoinField_management ("inFeatures" , "joinField" , "joinTable" , "fieldList")
```

I think a loop would be good here? But I did not understand that good how a loop works. I dont understand what that for XX in YY means. And I am not sure if I can do that thing: %Name%.

Any ideas, hints, suggestions?

**EDIT 7/8/14 4:00 pm**

```
import arcpy
import os

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wetland\\New_Folder"
ws = arcpy.env.workspace

#create a list of features
fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#loop through the list
for fc in fcl:
    basename = fcl.split("_")[0] #split name of features and only take the first word as a basename


    inFeatures = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_diss") #The table or feature class to which the join table will be joined.
    joinField = "WLType" #The field in the input table on which the join will be based.
    joinTable = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_full") #The table to be joined to the input table.
    fieldList = "WLType" #The field in the join table that contains the values on which the join will be based.

    #JoinField "JoinField_management (in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, {fields})"
    arcpy.JoinField_management(inFeatures , joinField , joinTable , fieldList)
```

Running this code I run into several problems. The biggest was the Error 000732 which said 'files do not exist'.
I converted all my shapefiles into a geodatabase which did the trick. The Geodatabase is in the folder "New_Folder".

But running the code now, still does not work. It does not Join one table to another.
I am wondering, where the problem is. Can anyone see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attached (untested) script takes the name of a feature class, splits it by "_" and uses that as a basename for the join operations.  The general idea is to use:

```
basename = fc.split("_")[0]
```

which converts, for example, `abc_clip_diss` to `abc`

Then, you can use that basename to create new variables with `os.path.join()`:

```
inFeatures = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_diss")
joinTable = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_full")
```

Finally, combine this syntax in a `for` loop so that you can iterate over a series of feature classes.

---

```
import arcpy, os

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\your\fcs'
ws = arcpy.env.workspace

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    basename = fc.split("_")[0]

    #set variables
    inFeatures = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_diss")
    joinField = "WLType"
    joinTable = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_full")
    fieldList = ["area_ha"]

    #JoinField "JoinField_management (in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, {fields})"
    arcpy.JoinField_management (inFeatures , joinField , joinTable , fieldList)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Ill try it in a sec. I have a couple of question to understand everything since my aim is not to get a "ready to use solution" but to learn something for further problems.

Loops:
It says `for fc in fcs:` while `fc` is not defined. How does the loop know how often it should iternate?

`fc.split("_")[0]`:
the zero means it starts with the first member of the created list, right?

`os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_diss")`
 Why do we have to write `os.path.join` and `ws` again?

Comment: and with your edit you just answered all my questions. Ill try to incorporate it!

Comment: `for` loops always work by iterating over a list.  To generate that list, we use `fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`, which generates a list of feature classes.  Keep in mind the list only contains the name of each FC rather than the full path.  `fc` is defined as a variable in each iteration, so you can call it within the loop.  The `for` loop will iterate over the entire list.  If you have 300 FC's in a workspace, then the `for` loop will iterate over all 300 FCs. `

Comment: It seems like the list `fcs` is empty. I get an errormessage `none type object is not iterable` in the line with `for fc in fcs:`

Comment: @Stophface Thanks for pointing out the error.  I have fixed the script.

Comment: Awesome. I think it is working now. there is an `arcpy` in front of `JoinField_management` missing as well I guess. 
Running this tool now I get another error message, but that is something different. A problem with the "executing tool". I will start a new fred for this. It looks like there is something wrong with arcpy... Thank  you Aaron!

Comment: Alright. An error occured running the script as it stands here error `000732`. It said the files were not there or do not exist. I had to convert all my shapefiles into a geodatabase and set the path new to that geodatabase in order to run the script. Now the script runs without an error, but does not add any fields to my tables. I keep that fred updated when I find a solution. Cheers!